# Does using Java code directly in Grails effects performance?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

This question comes at a time when Groovy already got excellent performance with static typing. But can I achieve speed equivalent to Java using almost everything like Java in Grails. Purpose of not using directly Java but using Grails is its excellence in web development. Since it is still .groovy, I am unsure if Java performance can be achieved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There will always be additional overhead running dynamically typed Groovy compared to Java.  However, you can optimise parts of your application which you want to speed up by moving Groovy code into Java classes.  You should then achieve normal Java performance for these bits of code.

If you really want to achieve "Java performance", you'll ultimately have to write Java, but you can get close by moving slow code to Java, and using `@CompileStatic`.

Answer (score 0):

In a grails app there are included grails library and groovy libraries that do much more computation because of dynamic typing of groovy.

So of course, there is performance degradation due to this much extra overhead for runtime.

Comment: so in this ecosystem, even if I write most of my code in Java, it will still affect performance ?

Comment: Of course, grails run-app make every code that you write to be used as grails way not the Java way.